# Create a new record with one2many

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, record

I want to create a new line in stock.picking, which will contain the date and the quantity:

```
 myRec.pack_lot_ids.create({'id': my_id,'qty': myQty})
```

There's no error,but the line is not created,SO I tried with

```
 myRec.pack_lot_ids.create(0,0,{'id': my_id,'qty': myQty})
```

There I have an error : only 2 args, 4 given.

Is there another way to create a line of one2many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myRec.pack_lot_ids.create({'id': my_id,'qty': myQty}) : this is correct you need to pass the parent ID to establish a link.

Comment: And the parent id must appear inside create()?

Comment: Yes, during creation of record parent id are used for linking one2many field.

Comment: Thanks, I passed the id of parent and it's ok, no need to use (0,0,...